# How do I add items to a listView (for duplicates increase quantity) and view in following activity?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, arraylist

I have an a gridView that has items, each item has a name and quantity. When I click the item in the gridView, I would like to add the item and the quantity to a dynamic list view that is in the same activity. If I click on the item a several times, the items quantity in the dynamic listView should be increased (no duplicate items are allowed.) This is my current gridView, I have removed the code that adds and a previous listView that failed and I am having it just toast for now:

```
    public class GridviewAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private ArrayList<String> listItem;
    private ArrayList<Integer> listPicture;
    private Activity activity;

    public GridviewAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> listItem, ArrayList<Integer> listPicture) {
        super();
        this.listItem = listItem;
        this.listPicture = listPicture;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return listItem.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return listItem.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder
    {
        public ImageView itemPicture;
        public TextView itemName;
        public TextView itemPrice;
        public TextView itemStock;
        public TextView itemAvailability;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup 
 parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder view;
        LayoutInflater inflator = activity.getLayoutInflater();

        if(convertView==null)
        {
            view = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.item_grid_row, 
 null);

            view.itemName = (TextView) 
convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
            view.itemPrice = (TextView) 
convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemPrice);
            view.itemStock = (TextView) 
convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemStock);
            view.itemAvailability = (TextView) 
convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemAvailability);
            view.itemPicture = (ImageView) 
convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemPicture);

            convertView.setTag(view);
        }
        else
        {
            view = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        view.itemName.setText(listItem.get(position));
       // view.itemPicture.setImageDrawable(listItem.get(position));

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

this is the code for the checkout fragment where the gridView is clicked.

```
    public class CheckoutFragment extends Fragment {

    private CheckoutViewModel checkoutViewModel;
    private EditText editText1;

    private GridviewAdapter mAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> listItem;
    private ArrayList<Integer> listPicture;
    private GridView gridView;

    DBHelper db;

    LinearLayout layout_total, layout_grid;

    private Button sum;


    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle 
savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_checkout, 
 container, false);

        db = new DBHelper(getActivity());

        Display display = 
getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int width = size.x;
        int height = size.y;
        editText1 = (EditText)root.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        editText1.setHeight(height/12);
        editText1.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);
        editText1.setFocusable(false);

        editText1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        editText1.setHintTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));

editText1.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#008577"), 
PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

        editText1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent cart = new Intent(getActivity(), 
CartActivity.class);
                startActivity(cart);
            }
        });

        prepareList();
        // prepared arraylist and passed it to the Adapter class
        mAdapter = new GridviewAdapter(getActivity(),db.getAll(), 
listPicture);

        // Set custom adapter to gridview
        gridView = (GridView)root.findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        gridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        // Implement On Item click listener
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new 
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int 
position,
                                    long arg3) {
//this is where the grid is clicked and items added to dynamic listView
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), 
mAdapter.getItem(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return root;
    }

    public void prepareList() {
        // listItem = new ArrayList<String>();

        db = new DBHelper(getActivity());
        List<Item> listItem = new ArrayList<>();

        listItem =  db.getAllItems(db.ITEMS_TABLE_NAME);
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_add_customer:
                //startActivity(getActivity(), 
NewCustomerActivity.class);
                Intent newCustomer = new Intent(getActivity(), 
NewCustomerActivity.class);
                startActivity(newCustomer);
                return true;
           /* case R.id.action_add_customer:
                return true;*/
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: User Interface in Your Adapter Class and implement and implement this interface in Checkfragment Class. and write mAdapter .notifydatasetchange after setadapter statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explain the situation a bit better. For now i assume your problem is that the items are duplicating the second list instead of appending the count. For this there is no
one line solution. What you need to do is once an item is selected in the grid, search if it exists in the second list. In that case update the quantity, otherwise add it to the list. Since your second list is based on a Table , you have to execute 2 queries. One to identify if the item already exists (Select Query) and other to change the value (Insert or Update Query). If i misunderstood please correct me so that i can help you better.

Why don't you return the model class in your GridView getItem(..) method instead of 'String' it should work like this

```
public class GridviewAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    ArrayList<GridModel> gridItems;
    //Constructor
    public GridviewAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<GridModel> gridItems) {
        super();
        this.gridItems = gridItems;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return griditems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public GridModel getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return gridItems.get(position);
    }

    //...add your getView...

}

//GridModel Should be Like So..
class GridModel {
    public String itemPicture;
    public String itemName;
    public String itemPrice;
    public String itemStock;
    public String itemAvailability;

    //or use private variables with getter-setter methods
}
```

Comment: What I want is to get the price of the items in the above grid, when I click on the grid, the toast basically shows me the name of the item, how do I get item from the view.